# Cannot reolve NetworkUtils class in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When I'm using NetworkUtils class in AndroidStudio, an error is being produced which says Cannot resolve symbol 'NetworkUtils'. Importing java.net also does not help.

Comment: Have you included that jar?

Comment: @Anand which jar?

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar in SDK